# Add www. when i delete www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

I have website `հttps://www. mysite.am`
when I write in browser mysite.am, it works normally and open `հttps://www.mysite .am`
when I delete first `www`. it opens `հttps://mysite.am` and don't work properly.
What write in *.htaccess file* to automated redirect all *mysite.am* domain to `www.mysite.am`.

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.am/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You should have properly configure `A Records` for your domain. this is not seem to me a .htaccess issue.

Comment: maybe problem in ssl sertificate?

Answer (score 1):

You must test https and www separately. Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.am%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```